# If a function copies an element of a slice to a variable, is it working with a pointer to that element or a copy?

Tags: go

Example situation:

There's a global struct holding a slice of structs.

```
type stctUser struct {
    user string
    privilege int
    created time.Time
}

type stctAllUsers struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    slcUsers []stctUser
}
var strctAllUsers stctAllUsers
```

There's a function that wants to operate on the users, and to reduce the time it's locking that global struct, I want to grab a user and release the lock

```
var strctUserTemp stctUser
strctAllUsers.RLock
for a := range strctAllUsers.slcUsers {
    if tmpName == strctAllUsers.slcUsers[a].user {
        strctUserTemp = strctAllUsers.slcUsers[a]
        break
    }
}
strctAllUsers.RUnlock
```

Is strctUserTemp working with a separate copy of slcUsers[a], or is it a pointer to that element of the slice? For example, strctAllUsers.slcUsers[a] is "Tom" and changing strctUserTemp.user = "Bob", would strctAllUsers.slcUsers[a] still be Tom?

(Before, it seems that making a copy of a slice to a new variable would mean changes to that new variable slice could change the original...so it assigned a pointer instead of creating a copy. Or am I misremembering?)

Update: Seeing as I was too stupid to take five minutes to test this out...here's a link to the behavior that had me questioning this in the first place, and I wanted to clarify the implementation before assuming I understood what was happening and creating a bug in the actual stuff I was working on. https://play.golang.org/p/ndmJ0h1z-sT

Comment: How hard would it be to test the user name change? 1 minute? But to answer your question: all assignment makes a copy. If you assign a struct value, the struct value will be copied (field-by-field). Care must be taken, as if a field is a pointer for example, the copy and the original will hold the same pointer, pointing to the same object.

Comment: It's a _copy_ like you said - you would have to explicitly make it a pointer for it to be just that

Comment: I was asking because I saw what I thought was contradictory behavior and wanted to make sure I wasn't running into errors from a lack of understanding how it's implemented...but snarky responses are still responses, I guess. Here's why I was originally asking about this.  https://play.golang.org/p/r2BIcI2mWwo

Comment: Added updated link in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most importantly: *assignment always copies*. However, it could be a copy of a pointer.

There are three basic scenarios:

1. You have a slice of values. You assign an element from the slice to a local variable, creating a copy of the value. There is no connection between the local variable and the slice element.
2. You have a slice of pointers. You assign an element from the slice to a local variable, creating a copy of the pointer. Changes to the pointed-to value will be reflected in any other use of the slice element, because the local pointer and the pointer in the slice point to the same memory.
3. You have a slice of values. You assign a reference to an element from the slice to a local variable (e.g. `myVar := &mySlice[0]`). The local variable contains a copy of the reference created by the addressing expression. Changes to the local variable's value are reflected by any other use of the slice element, because the local pointer points directly to the memory where that slice element is held.

Note that the last option means you'll have a fragile pointer - if you append to the slice and the underlying array moves around in memory you'll get some confusing behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the info; can you elaborate on what's happening in the playground link I added to the question?

Comment: It's almost a hundred lines, can you clarify which part you're asking about?

Comment: Lines 55 - 64, copying the slice to a variable

Comment: So #3 in the output? You're taking a copy of the slice. Both copies point to the same underlying array, so a change to an element in one is reflected in the other.

Comment: Okay, so the = to the slice is actually a set of pointers, but the = to an element makes a copy of what is being pointed to.

Comment: The slice is not a set of pointers (unless it is a slice of pointers, e.g. `[]*int`). A slice is a pointer to an array. See https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: Perfect! Great explanation!